# For loop is not successful after I use driver.back()

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I'm very new to Python (3.9 via Spyder) and am trying web-scraping. I'm having issues trying to keep a for loop working after using driver.back() within the loop (PLEASE NOTE: the alternative code that involves the command driver.goback[-1] or whatever also did not work for me). My goal is to download two sets of excel files from the following campaign page linked in driver.get (the excel files are found on succeeding pages after I click a specific election year from a dropdown menu). Python can download the excel file for the first option in the dropdown menu, but my code fails after the driver.back() line, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

A minor thing I'd also like to do is index my except: print by oppy (i.e., if the foor loop fails, tell me it fails for option value *i*  in the set of options). Here is my code (I know it is clunky, but the sleep(rand(...)) seemed to be the only thing to keep my Python to even run the first loop). Any help is appreciated!!!

```
#Calling to use Chrome to webscrape
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

#Create WebDriverWait times of 5, 10, 15 and 30 seconds
wait5 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait10 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait15 = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait30 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

#Getting link
driver.get("https://www.fec.gov/data/committee/C00716720")

#Get Two-Year Period drop down menu in PCC Homepage
select = driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//select[@id='summary-cycle']")  #get the select element            
options = select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option") #get all the options into a list

optionsList = []

for option in options: #iterate over the options, place attribute value in list
    optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

#Loop over all available two-year periods
for oppy in optionsList:

    
    try: 
        dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('summary-cycle'))
        dropdown.select_by_value(oppy)
        sleep(randint(5,7))
        
        #Clicks on "Browse receipts" button
        receipts = wait30.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="total-raised"]/div[1]/a')))
        receipts.click()
         
        sleep(randint(10,15))
         
        #Clicks on "Export" button for receipts
        receiptsexport = wait30.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/button')))
        receiptsexport.click()
         
        sleep(randint(5,7))
         
        #Clicks on "Download" button under "Your downloads"
        receiptsdownload = wait10.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/ul/li/div/a')))
        sleep(randint(5,7))
        receiptsdownload.click()
        sleep(randint(5,7))
        
        driver.back() #CODE DOESN'T WORK AFTER FIRST PASS
        sleep(randint(5,7))
        
    #If it doesn't work, tell me    
    except:
        print("clicking 'Browse Receipts' did not work for current election year")
        
        driver.back()
```

Comment: I guess you are getting `StaleElement` exception. Right? For what code line?

Comment: Most likely for oppy in optionlist use index based  and grab the option you want.

Comment: I do get a "DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated" warning. This is for driver.back() (line that says "#CODE DOESN'T WORK AFTER FIRST PASS"). I'm very new Arundeep, so I'm not sure what you're meaning there.